# How can I clean up this return type for neoism go-lang?

Tags: json, go, neo4j, neoism

This model I am trying to make with neoism is working now but I can't figure out how to make the return type shorter and or cleaner looking.
There must be a way to make this:
 `[]struct { UserId string "json:\"account.UserId\""; FirstName string "json:\"account.firstName\""; LastName string "json:\"account.lastName\"" }`

Into: 
`[]Account` or something

```
package models

import (
  "errors"
  "strconv"
  "time"
  // "fmt"

  "github.com/jmcvetta/neoism"
)

var (
  Accounts map[string]*Account
)

var (
  db *neoism.Database
)

func panicErr(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

type Account struct {
  UserId   string `json:"account.UserId"`
  FirstName     string `json:"account.firstName"`
  LastName      string `json:"account.lastName"`
}

func init() {
  var err error
  db, err = neoism.Connect("http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474/db/data")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

// map[lastName:PATRUS UserId:7f7014f9-bd59-4739-8e1b-5aebfa00f4c5 firstName:LARISSA]

func GetAccounts() []struct { UserId string "json:\"account.UserId\""; FirstName string "json:\"account.firstName\""; LastName string "json:\"account.lastName\"" } {
  stmt := `
    MATCH (account:Account) RETURN account.UserId, account.firstName, account.lastName
  `

  res := []struct {
    UserId string `json:"account.UserId"`
    FirstName  string `json:"account.firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"account.lastName"`
  }{}

  // construct query
  cq := neoism.CypherQuery{
    Statement:  stmt,
    Result:     &res,
  }

  // execute query
  err := db.Cypher(&cq)
  panicErr(err)

  return res
}
```

Here is another copy:
http://play.golang.org/p/14gzc0a_89

I am new to go and I am going off of these examples for neoism: 
https://gist.github.com/verdverm/b43444063995a7f5b913

There are many examples, but verdverm is always just outputting and not returning.

I have a controller as well where I would like to output the json.

```
package controllers

import (
  "github.com/astaxie/beego"
  "social/models"
)

type AccountsController struct {
  beego.Controller
}

func (c *AccountsController) Get() {
  c.Data["json"] = models.GetAccounts()
  // c.Data["json"] = "hello world"
  c.ServeJson()
}
```

Thanks for any help/tips for go newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package models

import (
  "errors"
  "strconv"
  "time"
  // "fmt"

  "github.com/jmcvetta/neoism"
)

var (
  Accounts map[string]*Account
)

var (
  db *neoism.Database
)

func panicErr(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

type Account struct {
  UserId   string `json:"account.UserId"`
  FirstName     string `json:"account.firstName"`
  LastName      string `json:"account.lastName"`
}

func init() {
  var err error
  db, err = neoism.Connect("http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474/db/data")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

// map[lastName:PATRUS UserId:7f7014f9-bd59-4739-8e1b-5aebfa00f4c5 firstName:LARISSA]

func GetAccounts() []Account {
  stmt := `
    MATCH (account:Account) RETURN account.UserId, account.firstName, account.lastName
  `

  var accounts []Account

  // construct query
  cq := neoism.CypherQuery{
    Statement:  stmt,
    Result:     &accounts,
  }

  // execute query
  err := db.Cypher(&cq)
  panicErr(err)

  return accounts
}
```

need to use the Account struct above the function and then make a variable inside and use pointer to var for the response of neoism db.

Answer (score 0):

Can getAccounts return an array of account pointers?

`func GetAccounts() []*Account {}`

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but right now it is returning the struct inside the GetAccounts function:  

    res := []struct {
        UserId string `json:"account.UserId"`
        FirstName  string `json:"account.firstName"`
        LastName  string `json:"account.lastName"`
    }{}

Maybe there is a way to use the struct above the function though?